# justgage refresh with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, justgage

I might just be being a bit dim here, or it might be my relative weakness with javascript, but I'm kinda stuck.

I have a justgage dial, showing number of people checked in an office, out of a total number.

I have a setInterval call just after the gauge is initiallised. But I want to update BOTH the number present, AND the total number, because both might potentially change. I can get the numbers via an ajax call to my own api - but because the ajax call is asynchronous, if I use

```
setInterval (g.refresh(myfunc()), 1000)
```

how do I get multiple returns out of myfunc.

Alternatively, if I do

```
   setInterval( myfunc(g), 1000)
   function myfunc(g){
       var foo=g;
       $.ajax(blah)
           .done(function(json){
                // no g here
           })
```

I have no reference to g on successful ajax call. (Though it is visible at var foo=g)

How do I get around this (multiple returns, or visible object)

Comment: g.refresh() it will update the gauge

Comment: g.refresh(baz()) - I want baz() to be a value pair for refresh - how would I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe there is a better solution but try to create the foo var as global and then you can use this in all the places you want.

Comment: sounds ugly, but I can live with ugly more than I can live with "can't get it working"